# Restore point-in-time data in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps Data Protection overview (here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/data-protection?view=azure-devops) it says the following:

"To protect against accidental deletion of data, Microsoft also takes point-in-time backups of both the blobs in Azure Blob Storage, and the databases in Azure SQL Database"

How can we access this point-in-time backups? If, for example, I want to restore data from one week ago, how do I do that? Couldn't find anything in the docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this yourself. You must contact support through an Azure Support Request and they can explain the options. Be aware that they can likely only roll back the whole organization by 1 week or stand up a replica of your organization. There is no partial restore apart from the built-in soft delete features where they can restore the contents without actually restoring from backup.

You can submit a support request here:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/